# Align menu next to title

Tags: html, css

How do I align my menu inline with my title on the left? The title should be aligned to the left and the menu on the right, but when I try to do that it keeps going below my title and the widths are good.

```css
* {
  font-family: "freight-sans-pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #5fbf9a;
}
.header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #5fbf9a;
}
.header a:hover {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.header li {
  display: inline;
}
a {
  transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
  -moz-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
  -o-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 130px;
}
.menu {
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 130px;
}
.content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #f0f5f7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <p><a href="www.lucafraser.nl" target="blank">Luca Fraser</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

        Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.</p>
    </div> -->
  <!-- <div class="footer">
    <h1>Made by Luca</h1>
</div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you aim, these CSS definitions can help:

```
.logo, .menu { display: inline-block; } ;
```

or

```
.logo, .menu { float: left; } ;
```

You can google to find out the differences.
If you are new to css, also check [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

You can use its navbar, nav components and grid system to easily position elements

Answer (score 0):

#### I would suggest using [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

First, remove the `line-height` from your `.logo` and `.menu`, then add:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```

#### See working example below....

```css
* {
font-family:"freight-sans-pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

body {
background-color: #5fbf9a;
}

.header {
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
height: 130px;
background-color: #5fbf9a;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between
}

.header a:hover {
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
}

.header p {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header ul {
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 18px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.header li {
display: inline;
}

a {
transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
-moz-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
-o-transition: 0.07s ease-in all;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.logo {
width: 200px;
}

.menu {
width: 400px;
}
.content {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 130px;
background-color: #f0f5f7;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <p><a href="www.lucafraser.nl" target="blank">Luca Fraser</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Work</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> You'll notice in the demo that the logo jumps to two lines when the window is too small. You can keep this from happening by adding `flex-shrink: 0` to your `.logo`